# Issues with SmartEdit after upgrading Spartacus to version 3.4.4

Tags: spartacus-storefront, smartedit

We have some issues with SmartEdit after upgrading Spartacus to 3.4.4.
Locally SmartEdit works fine, issues are present on our stage environment.
Contextual menu to edit components is missing on all slots but only on our homepage, and content of components is overlapping. All other pages don't have these issues.

We tried the following to solve this but nothing worked:

- updating Spartacus styles
- removing lazy loading, deferred loading and enabling SSR on components that are used on our homepage
- downgrading Spartacus to 3.0.0
- hiding component after component in SmartEdit to check if those issues are maybe caused by one of them

However, contextual menu shows up after changing route two times, i.e. going to login page, then back to homepage and repeating the step. When contextual menu shows up, content of components is not overlapping anymore.

What we also noticed is that locally we're using Angular 10, which is needed for the Spartacus 3.x, but somehow on our stage environment we have
[Angular 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQQWv.png). Also, in SE preview mode we see this [ySEEmptyClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1ERa.png) shown in slots.

Another issue we found in SmartEdit, when we open one i.e. one category page but directly on stage (not navigating from homepage) we see empty slots and a spinner - same for the PDP.

Any ideas on how we can solve these issues? Is anyone facing similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with SmartEdit on Spartacus version 4. It kept showing up with the loading spinner too.
What I did to fix it was add to my index.html the following line:

```
<script id="smartedit-injector" src="assets/webApplicationInjector.js" data-smartedit-allow-origin="localhost:9002, development_environment_url.com:80"></script>
```

Perhaps try adding all your URLs (staging, dev, prod, etc) to the data-smartedit-allow-origin field?